# How to cause maven to download any required files for a build?

Tags: java, maven

I am interested in having maven download *all* pom/jar dependencies for a build, prior to running a `mvn verify`. The reason I am doing this is I want to build in docker and have all the deps cached so they do not have to be downloaded every time I build as these rarely change.

I can get many of the deps cached with:

```
mvn process-resources
```

which pulls in and successfully caches most dependencies. However in my build I am still seeing things like:

```
maven-failsafe-plugin:2.13:integration-test
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.13/maven-surefire-common-2.13.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.13/maven-surefire-common-2.13.pom (6 KB at 67.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.pom (2 KB at 20.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/3.2/maven-plugin-tools-3.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools/3.2/maven-plugin-tools-3.2.pom (17 KB at 192.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.13/surefire-api-2.13.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.13/surefire-api-2.13.pom (3 KB at 32.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.13/surefire-booter-2.13.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.13/surefire-booter-2.13.pom (3 KB at 39.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.pom (17 KB at 183.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.13/surefire-booter-2.13.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.13/surefire-booter-2.13.jar (35 KB at 401.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar (309 KB at 1793.0 KB/sec)
```

Or a few others which also download like:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:reserve-network-port
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @
```

It looks like anything related to the *build* section of the pom.xml (or maven itself) is not pulled in when I run `process-resources`. I also have tried `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` but that also does not cache them.

How can I also download any deps from the `build` section of my pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

This command should do the trick:

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

According to their docs https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html:

> Goal that resolves all project dependencies, including plugins and reports and their dependencies.

Comment: This does not download the dependencies I list in the OP either, just the _project_ deps and not the build deps and in fact fewer of them than the ops I listed for some reason.